# dbms_output.put_line shows variable value but does not save to database

Tags: oracle, replace, toad, dbms-output

I am trying to save a value in a table after removing an & in the input variable.
When I print the value of the variable in dbms_ouput.put_line I get the output. but when I save the value of the variable to database, nothing is updated. Code below is a simplified version. Using toad 10.6 on oracle 11g

```
FUNCTION UPDATE_ADDRESS(ADDRESS VARCHAR2,
                    P_USER  VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    RetVal                VARCHAR2(32767);
    V_ADDRESS   VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('ADDRESS ::=' || ADDRESS); --this prints
    V_ADDRESS := REPLACE(ADDRESS, '&', '');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('V_ADDRESS ::=' || V_ADDRESS); --so does this

    UPDATE ADDRESS_TABLE
    SET ADDRESS = SUBSTR(V_ADDRESS, 1, 255) --this column does not get updated
    WHERE USER = P_USER;
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: You cannot execute DML inside a function without defining `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` in your declaration. You can add that to your function, or make this a procedure, which is what it should probably be anyway.

Comment: Is there definitely a column USER in the table and does a row exist where the value is the same as `P_USER`? P.S. your function isn't returning anything so this won't even compile...

Comment: Dear all, thank you for your comments. Kindly note that this is a simplified example of my problem. It has nothing to do with USER. USER is only used as a replacement for subno. The problem is that when I output the variable in dbms_output.put_line it prints it in DBMS output, but when I update with the same variable in table. it updates nothing.

Comment: @Wolf That's only true if the function is called from SQL, and even then it might perform DML on a different table if it's called from an UPDATE or DELETE, see http://psoug.org/snippet/FUNCTIONS-special-restrictions_868.htm

Comment: @Sarwar Then update your question. It doesn't make sense to paste code that does not reproduce your problem. Post a *minimal*, *reproducible* example with table definitions, content and expected outcome.

Comment: Update: It does not work in Toad but does in Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: We don't know what doesn't work at the moment @Sarwar... if your question remains the same you've got the correct answer already. As that isn't your actual question I can't see how anyone can help you.

Answer (score 1):

your column name USER conflicts with internal function with the same name, make it ADDRESS_TABLE.USER

@Wolf

tmp_func has DML operation and no PRAGMA. Just working....

```
create table tmp1 as select 1 n from dual;

create or replace function tmp_func return number is
v_n number;
begin
  update tmp1 set n = n + 1
  returning n into v_n;
  return v_n;
end;
/

declare
v_n number;
begin
v_n := tmp_func();
dbms_output.put_line(v_n);
end;
/
```

Output:

```
table TMP1 created.
FUNCTION TMP_FUNC compiled
anonymous block completed

2
```